# Sql server CASE expression columns indexing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

The query below is taking too long to run.
I suspect my inefficiency is because of the way I am using the CASE Conditions in the sub query.

Please help index these tables correctly to make this query efficient

The main Fact table contains about 60 Million rows

This is what IO statistics is hsowing

Table 'Dim_Dealership'. Scan count 4, logical reads 766, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Dim_Date'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Fact_Member_Accruals'. Scan count 3, logical reads 521, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Dim_Member'. Scan count 58617, logical reads 249549, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 64, logical reads 2424, physical reads 182, read-ahead reads 2298, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 81, logical reads 401006, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

```
SELECT 
    A_Code
    ,P_A_Code
    ,Region_Code
    ,Duration_Wave
    ,Country
    ,DateRollupLevel
    ,DateRollupValue

    --Enrollement Penetration Data 
    ,Enp_Num
    ,Enp_Den
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enp_Num AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enp_Den,0), 0) AS Enp_Rate

    ,Enp_Num_Auto_Nation
    ,Enp_Den_Auto_Nation
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enp_Num_Auto_Nation AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enp_Den_Auto_Nation,0), 0) AS Enp_Rate_Auto_Nation

    ,Enp_Num_QuickLane
    ,Enp_Den_QuickLane
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enp_Num_QuickLane AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enp_Den_QuickLane,0), 0) AS Enp_Rate_QuickLane

    ,Enp_Num_Top_Tier_Flag
    ,Enp_Den_Top_Tier_Flag
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enp_Num_Top_Tier_Flag AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enp_Den_Top_Tier_Flag,0), 0) AS Enp_Rate_Top_Tier_Flag

    --Enrollement Capture Data 
    ,Enc_Num
    ,Enc_Den
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enc_Num AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enc_Den,0), 0) AS Enc_Rate

    ,Enc_Num_Auto_Nation
    ,Enc_Den_Auto_Nation
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enc_Num_Auto_Nation AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enc_Den_Auto_Nation,0), 0) AS Enc_Rate_Auto_Nation

    ,Enc_Num_QuickLane
    ,Enc_Den_QuickLane
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enc_Num_QuickLane AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enc_Den_QuickLane,0), 0) AS Enc_Rate_QuickLane

    ,Enc_Num_Top_Tier_Flag
    ,Enc_Den_Top_Tier_Flag
    ,ISNULL(CAST(Enc_Num_Top_Tier_Flag AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(Enc_Den_Top_Tier_Flag,0), 0) AS Enc_Rate_Top_Tier_Flag      
FROM
(
SELECT
DD.A_Code
,DD.P_A_Code
,DD.Region_Code
,DD.Duration_Wave
,DD.Country
,'Year' AS DateRollupLevel
,'2013-01-01' as DateRollupValue


--Enrollement Penetration Data (Enp)
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsNumeratorEnrollmentPenetration = 1  THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Num
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsDenominatorEnrollmentPenetration = 1  THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Den

--AutoNation = 'Yes'
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsNumeratorEnrollmentPenetration = 1 AND DD.AutoNation_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Num_Auto_Nation
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsDenominatorEnrollmentPenetration = 1  AND DD.AutoNation_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Den_Auto_Nation

--QuickLane = 'Yes'
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsNumeratorEnrollmentPenetration = 1 AND DD.Quick_Lane_Enroll_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Num_QuickLane
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsDenominatorEnrollmentPenetration = 1  AND DD.Quick_Lane_Enroll_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Den_QuickLane

--Top_Tier_Flag = 'Yes'
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsNumeratorEnrollmentPenetration = 1 AND DD.Top_Tier_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Num_Top_Tier_Flag
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN FSE.IsDenominatorEnrollmentPenetration = 1  AND DD.Top_Tier_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enp_Den_Top_Tier_Flag


--  Enrollement Capture Data (Enc)

,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsNumeratorEnrollmentCapture  = 1  THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Num
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsDenominatorEnrollmentCapture  = 1  THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Den

--AutoNation = 'Yes'
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsNumeratorEnrollmentCapture = 1 AND DD.AutoNation_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Num_Auto_Nation
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsDenominatorEnrollmentCapture = 1  AND DD.AutoNation_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Den_Auto_Nation

--QuickLane = 'Yes'
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsNumeratorEnrollmentCapture = 1 AND DD.Quick_Lane_Enroll_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Num_QuickLane
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsDenominatorEnrollmentCapture = 1  AND DD.Quick_Lane_Enroll_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Den_QuickLane

--Top_Tier_Flag = 'Yes'
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsNumeratorEnrollmentCapture = 1 AND DD.Top_Tier_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Num_Top_Tier_Flag
,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN IsDenominatorEnrollmentCapture = 1  AND DD.Top_Tier_Flag = 'Yes' THEN  DM.Member_registration_ID END)) AS Enc_Den_Top_Tier_Flag

FROM dbo.Fact_Member_Accruals FSE WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Dealership DD ON FSE.Dim_Dealership_SK = DD.Dim_Dealership_SK
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Member DM WITH (NOLOCK) ON FSE.Dim_UDB_Customer_RepairOrder_SK = DM.Dim_Member_SK
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Date DT WITH (NOLOCK) ON Dim_RO_Closed_Date_SK = DT.Dim_Date_SK
WHERE 0 = 0

AND DT.Cal_Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2015-03-22'
AND DD.Launched_Date <= '2015-03-22'
GROUP BY 
        GROUPING SETS((DD.A_Code),(P_A_Code), (Region_Code), (Duration_Wave),(DD.Country))
)Mbrs
```

Comment: Have you checked what "statistics io" shows? It usually reveals where the problem is. Also assuming that there are no views or user defined functions involved here.

Comment: Also as a warning, using nolock can cause all sorts of strange issues to happen. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: What does the execution plan show as the biggest resource-hog?

Comment: I have added the result of IO Statistics to the question text